# problems with index of array

Tags: kotlin

I'm writing a function that allows you to remove certain numbers from an int arraylist.

My code

```
for (i in 1 until 4) {
        divider = setDivider(i)
        for(index in 0 until numbers.size){
            if(index <= numbers.size){
                if (numbers[index] % divider == 0 && !isDone) {
                    numbers.removeAt(index)
                }
            }else{
                isDone = true
            }

        }

         if(isDone)
            break
    }
```

the function to set the divider

```
fun setDivider(divider: Int): Int {
    when (divider) {
        1 -> return 2
        2 -> return 3
        3 -> return 5
        4 -> return 7

    }
    return 8
}
```

I do not know why the ide is giving me the error Index 9 out of bounds for length 9.

Comment: `if(index <= numbers.size)` Did you mean strict inequality here?

Comment: Because when you `removeAt` from `numbers`, `numbers.size` from the outer loop will keep with the previous value and it'll make an additional iteration.

Comment: I removed that if and it give me the same error (it was only a test)

Comment: what can I do to update the new size?

Comment: I solve using numbers.last instead of numbers.size but the function remove only five numbers and then it ends

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to remove items from the collection you are iterating - it requires great care. Note that if you are e.g. at index 5, you remove it, so old 6 becomes 5, next you increment index to 6, then you actually skipped one item without processing it. This is probably the reason why you did not remove everything.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Get a list of numbers that don't divide by any of provided dividers?

Comment: remove all numbers that are divisible by 2, 3, 5, and 7 from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author explained in the comments that the goal is to remove all numbers that are divisible by 2, 3, 5 and 7.

It can be achieved much easier by utilizing ready to use functions from stdlib:

```
val dividers = listOf(2, 3, 5, 7)

numbers.removeAll { num ->
    dividers.any { num % it == 0 }
}
```

It removes elements that satisfy the provided condition (is divisible) for any of provided dividers.

Also, it is often cleaner to not modify a collection in-place, but to create an entirely new collection:

```
val numbers2 = numbers.filterNot { num ->
    dividers.any { num % it == 0 }
}
```